# How do I get all characters after a space in C++?

Tags: c++

In C++, how do I get ALL of the text after a space. I am trying to make my own coding language, so I want the user to be able to enter (/print (text here)) and print the text the user has entered. I want this to be all in one line; without having the user to input the command, then input the thing they want to output. Thank you to anyone who replies in advance.

Comment: in C you could use something like `strchr()` (if you are storing the string an a `char[]`), in c++ you could use something like `find()` (if you are using the `std::string` object)

Comment: Check [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and the examples supplied in cppreference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Leveraging <algorithm>

The following will work with C++11:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

bool is_blank(char ch)
{
  return std::isblank(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
}

int main() {
  std::string inp = "print foo";

  auto it = std::find_if(inp.begin(), inp.end(), is_blank);
  it = std::find_if_not(it, inp.end(), is_blank);
  
  std::copy(it, inp.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
}
```

Run this code in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:22,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:22,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:22,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:22,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccctype%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%0Abool+is_blank(char+ch)%0A%7B%0A++return+std::isblank(static_cast%3Cunsigned+char%3E(ch))%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++std::string+inp+%3D+%22print+foo%22%3B%0A%0A++auto+it+%3D+std::find_if(inp.begin(),+inp.end(),+is_blank)%3B%0A++it+%3D+std::find_if_not(it,+inp.end(),+is_blank)%3B%0A++%0A++std::copy(it,+inp.end(),+std::ostream_iterator%3Cchar%3E(std::cout))%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:100,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%270%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g102,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Note that we're only iterating over the input string once. Also note that this solution leverages the algorithms which come with the C++ standard library - no raw loops required :-)

---

## Using `std::string`'s find functions

`std::string` has a ton of built-in functions. I'm pretty sure if C++ could be developed from scratch most of them wouldn't be there. But since we have them we put them to some use:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
  std::string inp = "print foo";

  const std::string whitespace = " \t";
  auto i = inp.find_first_of(whitespace);
  i = inp.find_first_not_of(whitespace, i);
  
  std::cout << inp.substr(i, inp.size() - i) << std::endl;
}
```

Run this code in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Citerator%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++std::string+inp+%3D+%22print+foo%22%3B%0A%0A++const+std::string+whitespace+%3D+%22+%5Ct%22%3B%0A++auto+i+%3D+inp.find_first_of(whitespace)%3B%0A++i+%3D+inp.find_first_not_of(whitespace,+i)%3B%0A%0A++std::cout+%3C%3C+inp.substr(i,+inp.size()+-+i)+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:100,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%270%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g102,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

I prefer the first solution since I find the last line a little more readable. [`std::copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) might also be slightly more efficient. Here [`std::string::substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) returns a temporary string which gets destroyed once `std::cout` has printed it. Not ideal in terms of performance which might or might not matter here.

Comment: `std::string` has the mathod `find`. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have added a second solution leveraging `std::string`'s find functions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way. It will give you all the characters after the first space in the string.

```
std::string x = "ABC CDEFG HIJKL";
x.substr(x.find(" ") + 1);
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Note that this doesn't handle multiple spaces or tabs between words correctly, though.